# Return HP Procurve 1400-24G to factory defaults

Tags: switch, hp

I've got a couple 1400 Procurves that I need to clear the configuration on. I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

I found a document for the 1800 series that said to loop a cable from port 1 to port 2 for about 40 seconds to restore the default configuration. I tried that method but it didn't seem to do much. Anybody know how to do this or where I can find the procedure documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are unmanaged switches.

They have no configuration you could change and thus no way to reset them.

> The HP V1400 Switch Series consists of two unmanaged switches. 
>   http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/12883-12883-4172267-4172303-4172280-4237515.html

Answer (score 2):

The HP Procurve 1400-24G (or V1400-24G) is an unmanaged switch, so simply removing the power and turning it back on will reset any counters and timers.

[See the 1400-24G manual for more information.](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/CoreRedirect.jsp?redirectReason=DocIndexPDF&prodSeriesId=4237515&targetPage=http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02563672/c02563672.pdf) (PDF)